# How to join across 3 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have table A:
NameID | Name
    1 Joe
    2 John
    3 Jacob
    4 Apple
    5 Roger

Table B:

```
SportID | SportName
    1 Basketball
    2 Soccer
```

Table C:

```
ID | NameID | SportID

    1 1 1
    2 1 2
    3 2 2
    ...
```

How do I join these tables such that I can get something readable?

```
Joe | Basketball
Joe | Soccer
Jacob | Soccer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `join` the tables together:

```
select a.name, b.sportname
from tablec c
    join tablea a on c.nameid = a.nameid
    join tableb b on c.sportid = b.sportid
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name "Student", b.sportname "Sports"
from tablea a, table b, tablec c
where b.sportid = c.sportsid and a.nameid = c.cnameid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(tableA.Name,' | ',tableB.SportName) FROM tableA,tableB,tableC WHERE tableC.NameID = tableA.NameID AND tableC.SportID = tableB.SportID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Joe | Basketball
Joe | Soccer
John | Soccer
```

I dont know how did you came up with `Jacob`